# Find duplicate code (Python and HTML Templates)

Tags: python, html, duplicate-files

I am searching a tool to find code duplication in Python code and HTML templates.

For Python I tried pylint, but it is very limited. See [issue1915](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1915#issuecomment-372017415).

But maybe this is not a task which needs to be done again and again for every programming language. Maybe there is a tool which can do this for any kind of text....

Needed features:

- find duplicate text in files.
- Whitespace changes should get ignored
- open source
- optional: Find duplicates even if some parts where slightly changed (for example a variable was renamed)

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @MartinThoma I did not find a solution. I did not actively looked for an answer during the last months since I switched the job.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give [PDM](https://pmd.github.io/) a try. It has a tool called "cpd" (copy paste dectection). You run it like this:

```
cpd --language python --minimum-tokens 100 --files your_code
```

### Pylint

I also found pylint too limited. This is how I used [the similarities checker](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#similarities-checker):

```
pylint --disable=all --enable=similarities your_code
```

Comment: https://github.com/seattlerb/flay might be worth a shot as well